# Formatted Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, format, cell

I would like to ask how to format the cell in MS Excel.

I have a text "**AB12122**" and I would like to format into "**AB12-122**" without using any formula.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just dug around Google, and it looks like the only way to do it is with a formula. The custom formatting is really only useful for numbers. I can however make it say AB12122AB12122AB12122AB12122-AB12122AB12122, if that's helpful. :)

Why can't you use a formula?

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. The cell is dynamic and I don't want to add another column for the formatted cell. The user will only input the value and cell will be formatted once the press the Enter key. That's why can't use the formula.

Comment: Dynamic would mean that the computer changes it, FYI. As far as I can tell, looking all through Google, I can't find a thing about formatting text like this, without some kind of formula.

Answer (score 0):

You may use character masking under Format Cells > Custom.