# Excel cell format

Tags: excel, format, cell

I would like to create a cell format in Excel without using formulas. 
The input is for example **03E02B** and the output to be displayed is: **03-E-02-B**

User will typ in value and after Enter, the value will have the cells format. 
Searched Google and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185812/formatted-cell-in-excel) but can't find any answers.

If it would be numbers only it can be done using this: **##"-"##"-"##"-"##**

But the value is actually all texts and I can't get it to work with text.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that custom formatting works with numbers, and not text... I think the only workaround would be to use a script/macro which will format the input and put the literal output in the cell.

Comment: Ok thanks, a macro is workable as well, but format cells would have been a little easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. It works only with numeric data formats (numbers, decimal, currency date etc.)

Also consider (if applicable) translating the user input into another cell with a formula:

```
=MID(A1,1,2)&"-"&MID(A1,3,1)&"-"&MID(A1,4,2)&"-"&MID(A1,6,1)
```